# how to find the value of the $k$ to make $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}}{x^{k}}=A$ exist?

Tags: limits

the question described as follow:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}}{x^{k}}=A$$
the $A$ is constant and $A\not=0$

and find the $k$ to make this limit exist.

---

and I did this:

$$let\space t\space be\space x^{1/15}\space, then \space x=t^{15}.$$
$$then \space \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}}{x^{k}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{t^{15}+t^{5}}-\sqrt[3]{t^{15}+t^{3}}}{t^{15k}}.$$
$$then \space \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{t^{15}+t^{5}}-\sqrt[3]{t^{15}+t^{3}}}{t^{15k}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{t\sqrt[5]{t^{10}+1}-t\sqrt[3]{t^{12}+1}}{t^{15k}}.$$

use taylor expantion:
$$then \space \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{t\sqrt[5]{t^{10}+1}-t\sqrt[3]{t^{12}+1}}{t^{15k}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{t(1+\frac{1}{5}t^{10}+o(t^{10}))-t(1+\frac{1}{3}t^{12}+o(t^{12}))}{t^{15k}}.$$

$$then \space\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{t(1+\frac{1}{5}t^{10}+o(t^{10}))-t(1+\frac{1}{3}t^{12}+o(t^{12}))}{t^{15k}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{5}t^{11}+o(t^{11})}{t^{15k}}.$$

$$then \space\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{5}t^{11}+o(t^{11})}{t^{15k}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{5}t^{11}}{t^{15k}}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{5t^{15k-11}}=A.$$
since A is a non-zero constant, so the  $t^{15k-11}$ should be $t^{0}=1$.

then we get $15k-11=0$ and finally, we find $k=\frac{11}{15}$.

---

Am I right?

suppose I was right.
but unfortunately I found the image of $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}}{x^{\frac{11}{15}}}$ in *quick graph* app.

the value of $f(0)$ goes to $\infty$ instead any constant.

which is wrong, the app or me?

if I was wrong, how to find the right k?

Comment: It looks right to me. What app were you using?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha agrees with you; see [this link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=power+series+(x%2Bx%5E(1%2F3))%5E(1%2F5)+-+(x%2Bx%5E(1%2F5))%5E(1%2F3)). What happened is probably your quick graph app didn't handle the numerical computations all too well.

Comment: You are correct. be confident.

Comment: Even if you graph it on Wolfram the graph is hard to interpret:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F5)+-(x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F3))+%2F+x%5E%7B11%2F5%7D&rawformassumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22

Which I suppose was part of the point of this problem.

Comment: @user357980 there is an error in your input, check here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+((x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F5)+-(x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F3))+%2F+x%5E%7B11%2F15%7D+from+0+to+.0001

Comment: @gimusi How is there an error in my input, when the graph of the function never gets higher than $0.14$ and we know that $A = 1/5 = 0.2$? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%7Bx+%5Cto+0%7D+((x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F5)+-(x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F3))+%2F+x%5E%7B11%2F15%7D

Comment: @user357980 I mean that in your previous input there was a typo in the exponent for the denominator https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F5)+-(x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F3))+%2F+x%5E%7B11%2F5%7D&rawformassumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22

Comment: @user357980 it is a numerical issue, if we go closer also graphically the limit seems to be confermed, look here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+((x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B3%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F5)+-(x+%2B+%5Csqrt%5B5%5D%7Bx%7D)%5E(1%2F3))+%2F+x%5E%7B11%2F15%7D+from+0+to+.000000000000001

Comment: I don't see what you are saying: $x^{11/5} = \sqrt[5]{x}^{11}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems correct indeed

$$\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}\sim x^\frac1{15} \left(1+ \frac{x^\frac23}5 \right)=x^\frac1{15} + \frac{x^\frac{11}{15}}5 $$
$$\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}\sim x^\frac1{15} \left(1+\frac{x^\frac45}3\right)=x^\frac1{15} +\frac{x^\frac{13}{15}}3$$

thus

$$\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}\sim \frac{x^\frac{11}{15}}5 $$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{ \sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}} }{x^\frac{11}{15}}=\frac15$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=t^{15}$. Then

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{x+\sqrt[3]{x}}-\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt[5]{x}}}{x^{k}}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{t^{15}+t^5}-\sqrt[3]{t^{15}+t^3}}{t^{15k}}=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\sqrt[5]{t^{10}+1}-\sqrt[3]{t^{12}+1}}{t^{15k-1}}$$

By Taylor the first terms of the development will be $t^{10}$ and $t^{12}$ (to a nonzero factor) and you need

$$15k-1=10.$$